# Exclude the formatting of this child from its parent

Tags: css

I have a CSS like below to create a certain background colour when hovering over the table.

```
.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover td ,
.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}
```

Within a `<td>` I have a `<div>`, which I would like to exclude from this hover colour madness.

```
<td>
 <div class="override_td">
    {% include '_test_edit.html' %}
 </div>
</td>
```

So I came up with an negation for the initial hover css.

```
.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover td:not(.override_td) ,
.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover th:not(.override_td) {
  background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}
```

But it seems I failed already miserably because my Aptana Studio shouts that

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking
>   a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument. Negations may not be nested; `:not(:not(...))` is invalid.
>   Note also that since pseudo-elements are not simple selectors, they
>   are not a valid argument to `:not()`.
>
> Example The following selector matches all button elements in an HTML
>   document that are not disabled. `button:not([DISABLED])` The following
>   selector represents all but FOO elements. `*:not(FOO)` The following
>   group of selectors represents all HTML elements except links.
>   `html|*:not(:link):not(:visited)`

So I am confused why it doesn't like my selector?

Comment: Just to confirm: aside from the warning from Aptana, do you see the rule *actually failing*?

Comment: why not .cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover td div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector looks well-formed (and follows the rules laid out in the Aptana warning message), and it works correctly, according to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNb5w/). You haven't mentioned an actual failure (only a complaint from Aptana), so I assume it will work just fine.

The reason for Aptana's complaint could be that it doesn't scan for invalid `:not` very closely. It's possible that simply because your selector string contains two `:not` pseudoclasses, Aptana assumes they are invalid, even though they are separated by a comma.

Comment: +1. Many Thanks. I have even created the case again on fiddle with Ajax. http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/XYcJv/  It works on fiddle. It doesn't work locally. Still looking into why that is... driving me nuts